# I want my java code to accumlate the total fee integers for each new set of inputs

Tags: java

When my code prints the total fee for one of the programs, I am able to input a new set of data. I want the total fee to accumulate.

```
package labFourPackage;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TuitionClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String name, emptyString;
  int fee, hours, pinNumber;
  int feeOne = 0, feeTwo = 0, feeThree = 0, feeFour = 0;
  String code;

  int i;

  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   System.out.println("Enter your last name ");
   name = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter your four digit pin number");
   pinNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
   emptyString = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter code - UnderGradCommuter  - UnderGradResident - GradCommuter - GradResident");
   code = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter credit hours studied");
   hours = keyboard.nextInt();
   emptyString = keyboard.nextLine();


   if (code.equals("UnderGradCommuter")) {
    fee = 500 * hours;
    feeOne = feeOne + fee;

   } else if (code.equals("UnderGradResident"))

   {
    fee = 550 * hours;
    feeTwo = feeTwo + fee;

   } else if (code.equals("GradCommuter"))

   {
    fee = 650 * hours;
    feeThree = feeThree + fee;

   } else if (code == "GradResident")

   {
    fee = 700 * hours;
    feeFour = feeFour + fee;

   } else
    fee = 0;

   System.out.println("The fee for student " + name + " is " + fee);

   System.out.println("The total fee for code UnderGraduate Commuting is " + feeOne);
   System.out.println("The total fee for code UnderGraduate Resident is " + feeTwo);
   System.out.println("The total fee for code Graduate Commuting is " + feeThree);
   System.out.println("The total fee for code Graduate Resident is " + feeFour);

   //System.out.println( "The total fee for students is " + (fee +     keyboard.nextInt()));

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by accumulating ? You want the total fees after you enter the inputs 3 times ?

Comment: Make a `totalFee` variable. Add all of the `fee` values to it inside the `for` loop. Print it out after the `for` loop.

Comment: Have you tried this after your if else loop, totalFee = feeOne + feeTwo + feeThree + feeFour; ? if you need a running sum.

Comment: Or, if it's a running total, print it out right where you have it commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a class variable named `int cummulativeFees = 0;`

And replace the commented last line with this -

```
cummulativeFees = cummulativeFees + fee;
System.out.println( "The total fee for students is " + cummulativeFees);
```

P.S. Try using a `switch` statement instead of an `if-else` ladder.